# How to loop, lookup and sum with two Python dictionaries?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am attempting to build a simple emissions calculator. The emissions factors for stationary fuel consumption (which are fixed for all users) have been entered into a dictionary with name `ef_stationary`. The three sources of combustion (which will vary across users) have been entered into a dictionary with name `warehouse`.

I would like to loop over the three sources of combustion, and for each item in the loop, multiply the corresponding emission factor by the quantity of fuel consumed. After completing the loop, the three calculated values should be summed. In this particular example the final answer should be 1200*70.62 + 2200*61.15 + 800*49.87 = 259,170.

I understand that `ef_stationary['Propane']` will pull out the appropriate emissions factor for propane, and `warehouse["forklift"]["quantity"]` will pull out the quantity of propane used. However, I am unsure of how to put these two bits together in a loop and then sum over the intermediate results.

I understand there are similar posts concerning looping and summing with Python dictionaries but none are close enough to my current problem to help me find a solution.

```py
ef_stationary = {
    "Natural Gas": 49.87,
    "Propane": 61.15,
    "Light Fuel Oil": 68.37,
    "Heavy Fuel Oil": 74.74,
    "Kerosene": 68.20,
    "Diesel Fuel": 70.62,
    "Marine Diesel": 68.16,
    "Gasoline": 65.22
}

warehouse = {
    "generator" : {
        "fuel" : "Diesel Fuel",
        "quantity" : 1200
    },
    "forklift" : {
        "fuel" : "Propane",
        "quantity" : 2200
    },
    "furnace" : {
        "fuel" : "Natural Gas",
        "quantity" : 800
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterate over the items in `warehouse`. For each item you can retrieve the quantity and the fuel type. With the fuel type as key you can retrieve the emission factor from `ef_stationary`. Then you can multiply them and add them together for all `warehouse` items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the data, it's clear that `ef_stationary` is meant to be used as a lookup for the per-unit prices and `warehouse` values are meant to be aggregated. So you can loop over the `warehouse` values, lookup the fuel prices from `ef_stationary` and multiply for the total fuel price.

```py
total = 0
for d in warehouse.values():
    fuel_type = d['fuel']
    price = ef_stationary[fuel_type]
    total += price * d['quantity']
```

The above can also be written as a one-liner using the `sum()` function:

```py
total = sum(ef_stationary[d['fuel']] * d['quantity'] for d in warehouse.values())
print(total)  # 259170.0
```

---

In case, fuel type in `warehouse` doesn't exist in `ef_stationary`, you can use `get()` to safeguard against that possibility. In that case, fuel types that don't exist in the lookup dictionary will be excluded from the total calculation.

```py
total = 0
for d in warehouse.values():
    fuel_type = d['fuel']
    price = ef_stationary.get(fuel_type, 0)  # <--- if fuel type doesn't exist, its price will be zero
    total += price * d['quantity']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to compute the total fuel used by the warehouse:

```
# Sum the total fuel used by the warehouse
total_fuel = 0
for item in warehouse:
    fuel = warehouse[item]["fuel"]
    quantity = warehouse[item]["quantity"]
    total_fuel += ef_stationary[fuel] * quantity

print(f"Total fuel used by the warehouse is: {total_fuel)")
```

**Output**:

```
Total fuel used by the warehouse is: 259170.0
```